# How I can send a message to only the specific user and when the user login can see the message in message screen using firebase & react native expo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have create contact form the admin to send messages to any user, and when the user access his account they can then view the messages in the messages screen.

Here is my contact form code:

```
const Contact =()=>{

    const [name,setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
    const [sendTime, setSendTime] = useState('')


  function renderForm(){
        return(
            <View>
                 {/*Name Input*/}
               <FormInput 
                     label='Name:'
                     value={name}
                     onChange={(value)=>{
                        setName(value)
                }}  
               />

                   {/*Email Input*/}
                   <FormInput 
                     label='Email:'
                     keyboardType='email-address'
                     value={email}
                     onChange={(value)=>{
                        setEmail(value)
                }}
               />

                   {/*message Input*/}
                   <FormInput 
                     label='Message:'
                     placeholder='Type something'
                     multiline={true}
                     numberOfLines={10}
                     inputStyle={{height:100,}}
                     value={message}
                     onChange={(value)=>{
                        setMessage(value)
                        
                }}
               
               />


               {/*Send Button*/}
               <View>
                 <AppButton
                    label='Send'
                    icon={icons.send}
                    disabled={!isEnableDonate()}
                    onPress={sendMessage}
                 />
              </View>    
            </View>
        )

    }

           {/*send Message to the specific user function*/}
    const sendMessage = async()=>{

        setLoader(true)

        db.collection('messages').add({
            userId:auth.currentUser?.uid,
            name:name,
            email:email,
            message:message,
            sendTime:sendTime
        })
        .then(()=>{
            Alert.alert('Message has been sent to the user successfully')
            setLoader(false)
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            Alert.alert(error.message)
            setLoader(false)
        })

        setName('')
        setEmail('')
        setMessage('')
    }
```

So when the user access his account can see the message in the messages screen.

Here is my message screen code:

```
import {db} from '../../firebase'; 
const MessagesScreen = ()=>{
     
    const message = db.collection('messages')
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
     
    {/*fetch messages which send to the current user by admin*/}

    const fetchData = async()=>{
        try {
            const list=[];
             await message
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot)=>{
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
                    const {userId,name,email,message,} = doc.data()
                    list.push({
                        userId,
                        name,
                        email,
                        message,
                     
                        
                    })
                })
    
            })
            setUserData(list)
            if(loading){
                setLoading(false)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            
        }
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchData()
    },[])

       return(
            <ScrollView>
                 
            <FlatList 
               data={userData}
               numColumns={1}
               renderItem={({item})=>(

                      <View>
                       <Text>Message:</Text>
                       <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                      </View>                     
             )}
             />
            </ScrollView>
           
        )
```

Right now admin can send message via contact form and add all messages saves in Messages Collections. However, what I'm trying to do is that I want the admin only send message to the specific user and user can view the message in the Message Screen.

Comment: If you have the UID of the user for whom the message is inside the document, you can [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to load only messages for the current user.

Comment: Yes, I do have UID of each user, but I don't understand what you mean ? Can you please explain it in a code so that I can understand easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to create a field in each message document called for example `recipient` and then get all messages where the logged in user matches that field:

```
const message = db.collection('messages').where("recipient","==",userData.uid)
```

This will fetch only messages that is meant for the current logged in user

**Example**

As admin when you create a message, might have the following collection **message**:

```
{
 text: "some text for my message",
 recipient: "uidA"
}
```

So as admin you create a new message like:

```
// Message for user with id *uidA*
db.collection('messages').add({
{
     text: "some text for my message",
     recipient: "uidA" //Id of intented user
    }
})

 // Message for user with id *uidB*
db.collection('messages').add({
    {
         text: "some text for my message",
         recipient: "uidB" //Id of intented user
        }
    })
```

Now as a user you can only access your intended messages with the following query

```
const message = db.collection('messages').where("recipient","==",userData.uid
```

Here userA will only access messsages where `recipient` is equal their userID

Comment: you mean I add field called recipient in each document or how ? but my question is how I can send let say Message A to user one and Message B to user 2 and message Z to user 30 and when the user one login can view Message A.?

Comment: Edited my answer with example

Comment: I'm a bit confused.! what I understand now that I should add new field in my contact form called recipient right? and when the admin fill in the contact form to send a message to user, in the recipient field what ID the admin should type in ? and how the admin will know the ID of each user ? like what I see in firebase when create  new user account  the user get uid  like this  LRteANBIQB9ka463. ? still confuse about the ID, and how the admin will know each ID for each user? because in your answer you wrote recipient  value as 'uidA' ,how do you get the ID and this message go to this ID please

Comment: I assume you have to list your users somehow for the admin to choose from? They probably have a display name so the admin can recognize each user. The admin does not need to know or see the uid of each user, just their information. You (as developer) use the uid to correctly connect and identify each user.

Comment: Alight , Now i totally got it.. which means when before the admin plan to send a message the admin should have the all users information and select either by name or id to send the message to the particular user. so I can even use names for each user to address the user and send the message not necessary use the uid  right?

Comment: I have implemented your example in my code but unfortunately getting this error;FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined.. I'm trying to retrieve only the logged in user by placing reciepient as use email as uid but it is not working any suggestion please?